# scraping news website aggregator by clicking on more news button using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape news headlines from this link: https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Business+&+Finance?type=ln

I want to expand news by clicking (using selenium) on the button **'view more headlines'** to collect the max number of news headlines possible

I created this code but failed to make the click to expand news :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
u = 'https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Business+&+Finance?type=ln'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(u)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")    
driver.implicitly_wait(60) # seconds

elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span:contains("view more headlines")')
for i in range(10):
    elem.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f'click {i} done')
```

returns: `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`

I tried using xpath selector:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="nn_container"]/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/a')
```

returns: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="rs-button-more js-button-more btn--primary btn--primary--no-spacing" href="#">...</a> is not clickable at point (353, 551). Other element would receive the click: <div class="alerts-scroller">...</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click button gets covered by an overlay element after the click. So, we use `javascript` to get to it after the first click. Here is the working program.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
u = 'https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Business+&+Finance?type=ln'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\bin\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(u)
time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
for i in range(10):
        element =WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,'btn--primary__label')))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        element.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        print(f'click {i} done')
```

Comment: the first click was done successfully, but the next one return error : Other element would receive the click: <div class="alerts-scroller">...</div>

Comment: @khaledkoubaa Updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the correct XPath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="nn_container"]/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/a').click()
```

Comment: returns error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="rs-button-more js-button-more btn--primary btn--primary--no-spacing" href="#">...</a> is not clickable at point (353, 551). Other element would receive the click: <div class="alerts-scroller">...</div>