# How to select item in dropdown list using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Dear Stack Overflowers,

I'm making a script that automatically pays off my CC's.  I'm having some trouble selecting an option in a dropdown list on the CC's webpage.  The code below has every step to complete the payment except the dropdown option that tells the script to select my checking as the form of payment.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import yaml
import time
conf = yaml.load(open(r'D:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\YML_Files\REI_Login_Credentials.yml'))
myREIUsername = conf['REILogin']['username']
myREIPassword = conf['REILogin']['password']

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=
    r'D:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\Executable_Files\geckodriver.exe'
)

def login():
   driver.get('https://onlinebanking.usbank.com/Auth/Login?usertype=REIMC&redirect=login&lang=en&exp=')
   time.sleep(4)
   driver.find_element_by_id('aw-personal-id').send_keys(myREIUsername)
   driver.find_element_by_id('aw-password').send_keys(myREIPassword)
   time.sleep(2)
   driver.find_element_by_id('aw-log-in').click()
   time.sleep(10)
   make_payment()

def make_payment():
    if (driver.find_element_by_class_name('accountRowLast').text) != "0.00":
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.soloLink.accountNamesize').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div[10]/div[2]/div[2]/a').click()
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.find_element_by_id('fromAccountDropDown-button').click()

        driver.find_element_by_id('rdoAmountOptionSingleCurrent_1')
        driver.find_element_by_id('btnTPContinue').click()
    else:
        driver.quit()

login()
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to select and the HTML for that section.

[image]

Here's a screenshot showing the options in the id tag.
[image: Here's a p]

I'm still learning how to use webdriverwait so I only have time.sleep() as the waiting method for now.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Very difficult without actually logging in. Do you get any error message?

Comment: I understand this is a toughy.  I can't really provide login information for obvisous reasons... I don't get an error, the script just ends because my else statement tells the script to close the window if it can't finish.

Comment: Check my answer. This is what I can help with.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047640/scraping-news-website-aggregator-by-clicking-on-more-news-button-using-selenium/65047686#65047686

Comment: Can you check what's in that SELECT tag if there's any OPTION tags.

Comment: @arundeepchohan I added a screenshot showing the options.  Looks like there are two options.  One with a value of "-1" and one with a value of "3".  I'm trying to select the second option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it work, although its a bit of roundabout way.  I used pynput and some keyboard inputs to scroll through the dropdown and then select the account I wanted to pay from.  Its not perfect but its a start and it works.  Here's the final code I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

import yaml
import time

conf = yaml.load(open(r'D:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\YML_Files\REI_Login_Credentials.yml'))
myREIUsername = conf['REILogin']['username']
myREIPassword = conf['REILogin']['password']

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=
    r'D:\Users\Matt\Documents\GitHub\Executable_Files\geckodriver.exe'
)

def login():
   driver.get('https://onlinebanking.usbank.com/Auth/Login?usertype=REIMC&redirect=login&lang=en&exp=')
   time.sleep(4)
   driver.find_element_by_id('aw-personal-id').send_keys(myREIUsername)
   driver.find_element_by_id('aw-password').send_keys(myREIPassword)
   time.sleep(2)
   driver.find_element_by_id('aw-log-in').click()
   time.sleep(10)
   make_payment()

def make_payment():
    if (driver.find_element_by_class_name('accountRowLast').text) != "0.00":
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.soloLink.accountNamesize').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div[10]/div[2]/div[2]/a').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        accounts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ui-selectmenu-status')
        accounts[1].click()
        keyboard = Controller()
        keyboard.press(Key.down)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.release(Key.down)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        driver.find_element_by_id('rdoAmountOptionSingleCurrent_1').click()
        driver.find_element_by_id('btnTPContinue').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_id('btnSubmit').click()
        driver.quit()
    else:
        driver.quit()

login()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have actually been working with dropdowns as of late so I hope this can be of help to you..
For the driver wait I have also had some troubles with it, but something that I found helpful was using: `driver.implicitilywait(amount of seconds)`

This command will essentially make it wait that amount of time looking or whatever for a certain element before (after the allocated amount of time has passed) determining that the webpage doesn't have the element specified.

As for the dropdown issue:

As you know there are different types of dropdowns on the web... (ie. Ones you hover over to get to the nested options, Ones that open when you click, etc.)
So in your case it really just depends.

So, if you would like to avoid changing this python script in the future, due to a website change, there are many ways to go about this:

So for instance your script says this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('fromAccountDropDown-button').click()

driver.find_element_by_id('rdoAmountOptionSingleCurrent_1')
```

Try this instead:

```
account_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id('fromAccountDropDown-button')
child_elements = account_dropdown.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*')
```

Now all of the child elements of the dropdown are saved into the `child_elements` var.
The way this works is when you use a '.' in the beginning of an xpath, it tells it to look  where it already is. ("." just means here basically)

From here you can then test things out (without making a payment on accident lol) by simply adding the following

```
account_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id('fromAccountDropDown-button')

child_elements = account_dropdown.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*')

length = len(child_elements) # Tells you how many elements were inside of the parameters you specified
# Essentially the child_elements var is an array that has all the elements that under the parent 'account_dropdown'
# You can target different elements in the array by using
child_elements[0]# This will give you the first element in the dropdown list
child_elements[1]# This will give you the second element in the dropdown list

# Once you determine which element you want to click simply do:
child_elements[int you want].click()
```

Another way that accounts for changes to the websites front end:

```
i = 0
account_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id('fromAccountDropDown-button')

child_elements = account_dropdown.find_elements_by_css_selector('*')
while i < len(child_elements):# While i is less than the amount of objects in the array
    selected_element = child_elements[i]# Grabbing one of the elements from the array depending of what number run this is through the while loop
    value = selected_element.get_attribute('innerText')# Grabbing the attribute innerText from the element
    if value == '<The account name you want>':# Checking to see if the innerText of the current element matches with the one we want
        result = selected_element
    else:
        i += 1

result.click()
```

If this doesn't work and if all the dropdown options are in the same class(which it seems that they are)you can try this:

```
# You can use any type of attribute EXCEPT XPATH for the parent element
accounts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ui-selectmenu-status')

# Then we do the same process as above with the len() function
print(f'Amount of dropdown options: {len(accounts)}')

# Once you have the amount above, then you can simply determine whether all the options are within that dropdown
#, or if the numbers don't match up, you know that class name is used more than in just that dropdown
i = 0 
while i < len(accounts):
    current_element = accounts[i]
    inner_text = current_element.get_attribute('innerText')
    if inner_text == <Insert the inner text of the option you want here>:
        current_element.click()
        break
    else:
    i += 1
```

This worked for me, hopefully this helps. Feel free to respond to this if you need some clarification on any of it.

-Carson

Comment: I'm going through your method but I get this error in the terminal: child_elements = account_dropdown.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Am I supposed to put something else in for './/*' ?

Comment: @Hiebs915 After doing some further research it seems I was mistaken as I had used the css selector method of this instead. Please see my updated post above

Comment: I'm trying your last method you posted.  The terminal prints out, "Amount of dropdown options: 2".  I know that the second option is the one I want to select but it doesn't do anything beyond printing the options.  Do I put the text in for "inner_text as if inner_text == '<External Checking 6771: f12000066>':" or "if inner_text == 'External Checking 6771: f12000066':"?

Comment: @Hiebs915 Yes that is correct you would want to put the expected contents of the innerText in that line `if inner_text == 'External Checking 6771: f12000066':`

What is script is doing here is it's targeting each child element 1 by 1 utilizing the while loop, then getting the innerText attribute from that element. Once it gets that information it then checks to see if it matches to the inserted string . ie. 'External Checking...'

Comment: So far no luck.  The inner text I'm looking for is, "External Checking 6771: 112000066".  I entered this in the two innerText locations in your while loop but the script only prints "Amount of dropdown options: 2" and then ends, it doesn't click on the second option.  I don't see the dropdown menu open either.

Comment: Are you able to click on the dropdown in the first place?
Also try this:
print the inner text inside the element so like this:
```
i = 0 
while i < len(accounts):
    current_element = accounts[i]
    inner_text = current_element.get_attribute('innerText')
    print(inner_text)
    if inner_text == <Insert the inner text of the option you want here>:
        current_element.click()
        break
    else:
    i += 1
```
If it doesn't print anything then there is something else wrong.
But if the elements do have innerText then it should print them, then try to use those as str

Comment: Yes, I can click on the dropdown.  It gives me two options, you can see them in the second picture I attached.  When I try to print the innnerText it prints, "None" twice on two separate lines.

Comment: @Hiebs915 please try using innerHTML and see what you get instead.

Comment: I found an error on my side... sorry. Now my terminal prints, "Amount of options: 2", "REI Card - 6137 Current Bal: $73.67 Available Credit: $19,926.33", and "Select from account".

Comment: @Hiebs915 Nice!!! Now you can simply try to click that bad boy by running the script mentioned above.

Comment: The first option isn't actually an option though.  I need to select the option that says, "External Checking 6771: 112000066" which doesn't print out in the terminal.  I would have expected the two options to be: Select from account and External Checking 6771: 112000066.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225369/discussion-between-cdraper-and-hiebs915).

Comment: I was able to get the script to run using some different methods. The solution used parts of what you posted. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. Your very welcome

Answer (score 0):

As i see it, you can click on the dropdown list, and then check the elements in the inspect element thingy on the right, and casually choose the element you want to click, which could look like this:
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(CSS-Selector of the button of the dropdown list).click
#That opens up the possibilities
Then continue by specifying the element from the list you would like to choose
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(CSS-Selector of the respective point you'd like to choose).click
This worked for me, not sure what kind of dropdown you have

Answer (score 0):

To select the option 3 from that Select tag.

```
sel = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='fromAccountDropDown']"))
sel.select_by_value("3")
```

You can also select by visible text to match the account you want.

```
sel.select_by_visible_text("External Checking 6771: f12000066")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Comment: I tried both of your methods but get this error message in the terminal:

selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <a>

Comment: Try this one out.

Comment: I now get this error message in the terminal:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //select[@id='fromAccountDropDown-button']

Comment: Should just be fromAccountDropDown.

Comment: Sorry, I tried without the "-button" because I thought that was the problem too.  After removing "-button" I get this message: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view

Comment: I did notice when I run the script the dropdown menu does not get selected, at least not visibly.  I'd expect to see the dropdown selected, the options to show, and then one of the options get selected.

Comment: have any other ideas?